# How to use ちょうさします？

Tags: grammar, word-requests

I have encountered a sentence in a localized Nihongo book here in the Philippines, and I think this expression is not for beginners.

Translate:

> Are you looking into something interesting?
>
> あなたなにかおもしろい（？）をちょうさしますか。

I am not confident that this is correct.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Japanese sentence is your attempt to translate the English sentence?

Comment: Yes...so I'm sure if it is correct. So, I'm asking for opinions of the experts here :)

Comment: Are you looking for a word that can fit in the blank or how to use the verb *調査する*?

Comment: That question mark is I'm not sure of my translation using 調査する

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more natural translation.
あなたは何か面白い(or 興味深い)事を調査していますか？

How to use 調査する:
あなたはトラブルの原因を調査しましたか？

はい、調査しました。
いいえ、調査していません。